# Differing behaviour when shifting bits in java

Tags: java

I'm working with bit shifting in Java and have the following piece of code that works as expected:

```
final byte value = 1;
final int shift = 1;
byte result = value << shift;
```

This produces the value `2` as expected.  If however I attempt to extract this into a method like so:

```
private void shiftAndCheck(final byte value, final int shift) {
  byte result = value << shift;
}
```

This results in a compilation error:

```
java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

The question is what is it about the method that causes this to fail?

Comment: [the type of `0`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/0zGzPygyJSU)

Comment: consider: `byte b = 1 + 1;` is OK, but `byte b = byteVar + 1;` is not ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `value` and `shift` are compile-time constants in this snippet:

```
final byte value = 1;
final int shift = 1;
byte result = value << shift;
```

then the compiler inlines their values (replaces all the occurrences of `value` and `shift` with their actual values of `1`) and can verify before Runtime that the result of `value << shift` won't cause any loss of precision.

---

Meanwhile, for the second snippet:

```
private void shiftAndCheck(final byte value, final int shift) {
  byte result = value << shift;
}
```

the compiler has no evidence that `shift` will represent such value, which wouldn't cause loss of precision and that's why raises a compilation error.

If compilation was possible in this case, then you'd have been able to do `shiftAndCheck(1, 32);` which would result in overflowing the `byte` type.

Comment: `value` is `byte` type so why message **from int to byte**. is `value` promoted to `int` before or after applying shift?

Comment: Because by default the numeric operators (including `<<`) produce `int` results.

Comment: I typed code (function )of question and don't get the error message mentioned in question, I get **Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte**  (for line `byte result = value << shift;` inside function ) which is pretty clear about problem. I am on Java7 and Eclipse 4.4.1.Not sure if this message varies from platform to platform or some IDE settings.

Comment: Am on Java 1.8.0_60 on OSX

Answer (score 0):

By default arithmetic operations on non floating point number produce an `int` result

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void shiftAndCheck(final byte value, final int shift) {
        byte result = (byte) (value << shift);
    }
```

As @Konstantin already said it returns `int`, so either cast it into byte or use `int result`.